# How do I get started in Virtonomics?

Tags: virtonomics

I'm slowly but surely falling for [Virtonomics](http://virtonomics.com/), but I haven't found yet a good tutorial or help site (yes, there is a [wiki](http://wiki.virtonomics.com) but it's a bit lacking insofar as helping one move his first steps).

Are there any suggestions or tutorials available to help learn this game?

Answer (score 2):

[This website](http://virtonomicsfan.wordpress.com/) holds a number of tutorials, walkthroughs and video links for Virtonomics.

Click '[Previous Entries](http://virtonomicsfan.wordpress.com/page/2/)' at the bottom of the page to see more (I missed this at first glance).